# Unresolvable Ambiguity problem on Join Tables

Tags: mysql

I have searched for all answers, but nothing works. Somehow this query gives me the ambiguity error or 'ID':

```
SELECT wpp.ID AS theid, s.ID AS supplierid, post_title, wp_terms.name AS category 
FROM wp_posts AS wpp
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wpp.ID = object_id
LEFT JOIN wp_terms ON term_taxonomy_id = term_id
LEFT JOIN wp_teleapo_supplier AS s ON wpp.post_author = s.ID
WHERE post_type = 'post'
AND (post_title LIKE '%bag%'
OR wp_terms.name LIKE '%bag%'
OR post_content LIKE '%bag%')
GROUP BY ID
```

the problem lies when I added this line:

```
LEFT JOIN wp_teleapo_supplier AS s ON wpp.post_author = s.ID
```

But I don't see what I'm doing wrong... Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GROUP BY ID`. That's where the problem is. MySQL can't guess which table this column `ID` belongs to. There is an `ID` column in both the added `wp_teleapo_supplier` table and in one of the 3 others (I guess the `wp_posts` one).

All your column references should be prefixed with the table name (or alias): (`object_id`, `term_id`, `post_type`, `post_title`, `post_content`, `ID`). The only reason that these other references did not produce this error is because you were lucky and they only appeared in a single table, from the 4 tables in the `FROM` clause.

(some of the prefixes may be wrong. But if they are, you'll get an error and you can correct them:)

```
SELECT wpp.ID AS theid, s.ID AS supplierid, wpp.post_title, t.name AS category 
FROM wp_posts AS wpp
  LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships AS r ON wpp.ID = r.object_id
  LEFT JOIN wp_terms AS t ON term_taxonomy_id = t.term_id
  LEFT JOIN wp_teleapo_supplier AS s ON wpp.post_author = s.ID
WHERE wpp.post_type = 'post'
  AND (wpp.post_title LIKE '%bag%'
    OR t.name LIKE '%bag%'
    OR wpp.post_content LIKE '%bag%')
GROUP BY wpp.ID ;
```